# onClick event listener not working for activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick

I have created a new Activity with a button that when clicked gives the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method sendPasswordEmail(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.Button with id 'sendPasswordEmailButton'
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4479)
at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4443)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the Activities XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/loginBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.ForgotPasswordActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/vetical_margin_medium"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/centerButtonWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/centerButtonHeight"
        android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_dark_frame"
        android:textColor="@color/inputColour"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/sendPasswordEmailButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="sendPasswordEmail"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Java code for the Activity:

```
public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
    }

    public void sendPasswordEmail() {

         // do something
        }
    }
}
```

The two previous activities I implemented in the same way, both have buttons and associated click listeners that work fine.

```
Compile Sdk Version: API 23: Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)
Min Sdk Version: 16
Target Sdk Version: 22
```

Here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="crm.geoalertapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activities.LoginActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can someone suggest why the onClick event listener is not currently working with this Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change :

```
public void sendPasswordEmail() { ... }
```

to

```
public void sendPasswordEmail(View view) {
    // Handle click on the button
}
```